# How to use scroll wheel as input on react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to be able to use the scroll wheel for changing values on my site instead of scrolling. More simplified I want `value` to go up by one when I scroll up one step on the mouse and go down by one when scrolling down. How do I do this?

Comment: Please may you share you current attempt as a text-based [mcve] and where it currently doesn't work?

Comment: Please search first man. You can use `onwheel` event. [Here is a demo](https://codepen.io/dattwood/pen/zYvPgxL).

Comment: Sorry, but I can't do that. The thing I am working on is confidential. But I just want the general way to do it and I'll implement it my own way.

Comment: _"The thing I am working on is confidential"_ - that's not a reason not to share a small demo

Answer (score 0):

Using state and ref you can control that y displacement.

```
class ScrollAwareDiv extends React.Component {   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
        this.myRef = React.createRef()
        this.state = {scrollTop: 0}   
    }

    onScroll = () => {
         const scrollY = window.scrollY
         const scrollTop = this.myRef.current.scrollTop
         console.log(`onScroll, window.scrollY: ${scrollY} myRef.scrollTop: ${scrollTop}`)
         this.setState({
               scrollTop: scrollTop
          })   
    }

  render() {
    const {
      scrollTop
    } = this.state
    return (
      <div
        ref={this.myRef}
        onScroll={this.onScroll}
        style={{
          border: '1px solid black',
          width: '600px',
          height: '100px',
          overflow: 'scroll',
        }} >
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
      </div>
    )   } }

ReactDOM.render(   <ScrollAwareDiv />,   document.getElementById('root') );
```

Check this pen: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JohnReynolds57/pen/NLNOyO?editors=0011)

Comment: This does not answer OP's question of using a scroll wheel to control a value.